# AWS quicksight custom query giving a wrong count

Tags: postgresql, amazon-quicksight

I am using a custom query like this-
select * from my_table where id not in (select id from my_table where order_date <= '2022-01-01' and delivery_status in ('Pending'));

I am using it because i have to exclude those orders from my table where delivery_status is pending before the start_date and this date can be a random date which i want to add filter to in the quicksight .
But i am getting a wrong data when i add filter for this column in the analysis . it gives the result without considering the inner query in the analysis.
Any suggestions on whether i need to change the query or regarding analysis will be much appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery. Your query says "get stuff where id not in a list where the status is pending.

Try.

```
select * from my_table where order_date <= '2022-01-01' and delivery_status = 'Pending'
```

Comment: actually i have to exclude those records which is having date <= '2022-01-01' and in pending status and this date field i want to keep dynamic so that whenever we filter with any date it will always exclude the count of pending orders before that date and give us the remaining count..Any suggestions on this .?

Comment: Ok,so 

select * from my_table where order_date => '2022-01-01' and delivery_status != 'Pending'

Comment: i only have to exclude the pending records before the start date , after the start date if the status is pending i have to count that records as well ..thats why i used the not in clause in my query .so the above query would give wrong results to me..